# How to read line by line a txt file using fgets in C

Tags: c, file, data-structures, linked-list

I'm creating a GIF maker program in C. part of the file management I load a .txt file into a linked list. I wanted to load line by line using fgets, but for some reason my program got into an infinite loop. here is the code I wrote:

```
/*
Use: create a linked list from the .csv files and return it's head
Input: None
Output: head
*/
FrameNode* loadProject()
{
    FrameNode* head = NULL;
    FrameNode* curr = NULL;
    FrameNode* newNode = NULL;

    FILE* project = NULL;
    char* path = NULL;
    char line[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0 }; 

    printf("Enter the path of the project (including project name):\n");
    path = myFgets();

    project = fopen(path, "r");

    if (project)
    {
        // create the list head
        fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project);
        head = loadNode(line);
        curr = head;

        while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project) != EOF)
        {
            // connect new node to the list
            newNode = loadNode(line);
            curr->next = newNode;
            // update current node to be the new one
            curr = newNode;
            
        }

        fclose(project);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error! canot open project, Creating a new project\n");
    }


    free(path);
    return head;
}
```

If anyone understand what's causing the **infinite loop please answer** down below

Comment: Stripping this down to an actual [mcve], raising the warning levels, and turning on treat-warnings-as-errors, the problem becomes apparent. [**See here**](https://godbolt.org/z/WEq3abr81). I suggest you jack up your warning levels and most-certainly treat **all** warnings as errors, because in nearly all cases that's *exactly* what they are.

Comment: change while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project) != EOF) to while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project))

Comment: @WhozCraig Your comment is actually better advice than the two current answers.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project) != EOF)
```

is wrong.

[`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) returns the pointer passed as the first argument on success and `NULL` on failure. It won't return `EOF`.

The line should be:

```
while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project))
```

or

```
while (fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, project) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, a null pointer is returned by `fgets()` and not EOF. So if you check for `!= EOF`, you never exit the loop.